# Write GET request for docker

Tags: docker, get, request, get-request

`Dockerd` daemon gives me such output:

```
ERRO[2857] Handler for GET /v1.26/containers/jupyter-user/json returned error: No such container: jupyter-user
```

How can I write GET-request in terminal to `docker` `daemon` to see such output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker exposes restful API on its daemon, you can use any CLI HTTP client tool to get such information. Docker daemon option `-H` is where it listens incoming requests. Take `cURL` as example:

- If your docker daemon only binds to unix domain socket like `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, then you need the latest `cURL` which supports `--unix-socket` option, I'm using `curl 7.52.1` to run the following command on docker host:

  ```
  $> curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.23/containers/unexisted_container/json
  No such container: unexisted_container
  ```
- If your docker daemon binds to TCP port like `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4322`, the above command would be:

  ```
  $> curl http://<host_ip>:4322/v1.23/containers/unexisted_container/json
  ```

You can refer to [docs of docker engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/getting-started/) for more details.

Comment: What does `v1.23` stands for?

Comment: It's API version, you can get it by `docker version`.

Comment: BTW, the official docs is https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/, there're also many other versions.